# Legacy standard C library headers and overloaded C++ functions

Tags: c++, legacy, standard-library

C++ language standard says in **D.5**

> **2** Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves
>   as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the
>   corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace
>   scope. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or
>   defined within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std` and are
>   then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit
>   using-declarations (7.3.3).
>
> **3** [ Example: The header `<cstdlib>`
>   assuredly provides its declarations and definitions within the
>   namespace `std`. It may also provide these names within the global
>   namespace. The header `<stdlib.h>` assuredly provides the same
>   declarations and definitions within the global namespace, much as in
>   the C Standard. It may also provide these names within the namespace
>   `std`. —end example ]

This seems to state rather explicitly ("... each name ...", "...the same declarations...") that the old-style `<name.h>` headers must provide the same set of declarations as the new-style `<cname>` headers, but in global namespace. No exception is made for C++-specific overloaded versions of various C functions, for one example.

That appears to mean that `<math.h>` must provide three versions of `sin` function: `sin(float)`, `sin(double)` and `sin(long double)` in global namespace. This, in turn, means that the following C++ code should fail overload resolution

```
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  sin(1);
}
```

It does fail under MSVC++ compiler, but it compiles successfully under GCC and Clang. So, does GCC just ignore the standard requirement with regard to deprecated old-style headers? Or do I somehow misinterpret the wording in the standard?

Comment: Section 17.6.2.3.1 allows an implementation to give `extern "C"` linkage to names from the C standard library declared with external linkage (although it recommends not doing so). If an implementation did this, it wouldn't be able to define three different versions of `sin()`.

Comment: I think you meant to say <cmath> must provide three versions. . . since math.h is the C header file. So, with that in mind, there won't be any overload issues since there is only one version of sin but three of std::sin.

Comment: @iheanyi: Header files can easily be cross-compilable between C and C++. If nothing else works, `#ifdef __cplusplus` can always save the day.

Comment: Yes and no. You can't include <math.h> and then use std::sin because it doesn't exist in math.h. #ifdef __cplusplus or not.

Comment: @iheanyi: Er... What does this have to do with `std::sin` specifically? Firstly, the question is about `sin` in `math.h`, not about `std::sin`. Secondly, even though it is not the topic, the C++ standard actually states that `math.h` is *allowed* to additionally provide these names in namespace `std` (see the standard quote above)

Comment: @iheanyi: It appears that you are caught in a misguided belief that C++ implementations are somehow required to use "original" "pure C" implementations of `<name.h>` headers. In reality this is not even remotely the case.

Comment: No, I don't have such a belief. But someone making a blanket statement that they can use c and c++ headers interchangeably by simply ifdeffing _cplusplus clearly has no idea what they are talking about. Just because something is allowed doesn't mean it will happen. I was responding to your comment "Header files can easily be cross-compilable between C and C++". If that was offtopic, perhaps you shouldn't have written the comment. Your own misunderstandings in the question you posted indicate you are a bit shaky on the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @hvd's comments I have seen the light, it turns out MSVC is correct and GCC should be complaining about the ambiguity as well.

The only differences between including `<cmath>` vs `<math.h>` are where the names are originally scoped, which is in `namespace std` for the former, and the global namespace for the latter (implementations are free to provide the names in the other namespace as well, but this isn't mandated), and the fact that including the `.h` variants of C headers is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, but how does that agree with what D.5 says? It basically says that `math.h` must provide the same declarations as `cmath` does.

Comment: @AndreyT [headers] "4 **Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D**, the contents of each header cname shall be the same as that of the corresponding header name.h, [...]". I guess the wording is ambiguous in D.5 though.

Comment: @AndreyT Come to think of it, it isn't ambiguous: `In addition to the double versions of the math functions in <cmath>` the overloads aren't technically part of `<cmath>` at all. I guess they are magically included by the preprocessor fairy.

Comment: It's not ambiguous at all, and doesn't say what you say it does. C specifies `double sin(double);` in `<math.h>`. C++ specifies `<cmath>` is like C's `<math.h>`, plus it adds `float sin(float);` and `long double sin(long double);` in addition to the `double` version. C++ then specifies that `<math.h>` is like C++'s `<cmath>`, except that the names are declared in the global namespace. There is no indication anywhere that C++'s `<math.h>` matches C's `<math.h>`. C++'s `<math.h>` is required to provide those overrides unless you can find an explicit statement in the standard otherwise.

Comment: @hvd As my second comment points out, it doesn't sound like the overloads are part of `<cmath>` in the first place. Surely the wording would have been something like "In addition to the double versions of the math functions in the Standard C library header <math.h>" instead?

Comment: @user657267 They would mean the same thing, since the earlier text already stated that C++'s `<cmath>` declares the same `double sin(double);` as C's `<math.h>`.

Comment: @user657267 The result is that C++ declares `float sin(float);`, `double sin(double);`, and `long double sin(long double);` in `<cmath>`, and starting from that result, it's easier to see how you can get there: "in addition to the `double` versions ... in `<cmath>`" refers to `double sin(double);`, and `float sin(float);` and `long double sin(long double);` are added to that.

Comment: @hvd It took me a while but I think I finally get it. I had understood annex D as heavily implying that the .h headers were meant to be virtually identical to the C standard library ones. Of course I can't actually delete my answer now...

Comment: @user657267 You can edit your answer, though. Radically changing the text of an existing answer is typically not well-received, but in this case, like you say, you don't have an option to delete your old one, so I think it'd be the best option to go for.